# Managing read state in event sourcing: How to prevent duplicate data when adding new events?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

How does one manage read state within an event sourcing infrastructure ?
Lets say I receive a new event to add a user. Before I can add the user to the event store I will need to ensure the user does not exist.
Considering event stores can't be queried like a normal RDBMS, how would I aggregate the events into such a way that I am able to query it ?

I am using EventStoreDB.

Comment: hey buddy, did you find any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

No direct experience with Event Store, but in most event sourcing systems, you can query for the existence of a stream and replay only the events which were persisted to that stream.  If you're writing events (at least the creation etc. events) for a given user to a stream dedicated to that user, then the non-existence of that stream is absolute proof that the user doesn't already exist.  If doing this, one doing DDD would say that you are treating user as an aggregate root: your check is effectively "load this user".

If for whatever reason you're not keying the event stream by user, the typical practice would be to have a read model derived from the events which can answer the question: "does this user exist?".  This read model would be eventually consistent (there might be an observable delay between user creation and this model visibly updating).  This opens the possibility of a user being created twice in a time window, so you would have some process (could be automated, it might have to be manual) to deal with a conflict here (e.g. deciding that the two users are in fact the same and merging them into one user (e.g. someone hit refresh or whatever) or deleting the later one): this is ultimately a domain logic consideration.